# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre TRUNCATE y DELETE?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `TRUNCATE` y `DELETE` en SQL Server 2008 o superior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Las diferencias serían estas en SQL Server > 2008:**

```
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|                Truncate                |                    Delete                    |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Es posible hacer rollback              | Es posible hacer rollback                    |
|                                        |                                              |
|                                        |                                              |
| Ejemplo:                               | Ejemplo:                                     |
| BEGIN TRAN                             | BEGIN TRAN                                   |
| TRUNCATE TABLE #Personas               | DELETE FROM #Personas                        |
| SELECT * FROM #Personas                | SELECT * FROM #Personas                      |
| ROLLBACK                               | ROLLBACK                                     |
| SELECT * FROM #Personas                | SELECT * FROM #Personas                      |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Truncate resetea el campo identity de  | Delete no resetea el campo identity de la    |
| la Tabla                               | Tabla                                        |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Bloquea la tabla completa              | Bloquea solo la fila a borrar                |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Es un comando DDL                      | Es un comando DML                            |
| (Data Definition Language)             |(Data Manipulation Language)                  |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| No se puede usar WHERE                 | Se puede usar WHERE para filtrar las filas   |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| El trigger de la tabla no se ejecuta   | El trigger de la tabla sí se ejecuta         |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Sintaxis:                              | Sintaxis:                                    |
| 1) TRUNCATE TABLE #Personas            | 1) DELETE FROM #Personas                     |
|                                        | 2) DELETE FROM #Personas  WHERE              |
|                                        |    Id IN (1,2,3)                             |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**Acá algunos ejemplos:**

**Ejemplo básico**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB.DBO.#Personas') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Personas

CREATE TABLE #Personas 
    (IdPersona int identity(1,1),
     Nombre nvarchar(20))

INSERT INTO #Personas VALUES ('Pablo')
INSERT INTO #Personas VALUES ('Juan')
INSERT INTO #Personas VALUES ('Carlos')

BEGIN TRAN                            
TRUNCATE TABLE #Personas                
SELECT * FROM #Personas  /*1*/                              
ROLLBACK                               
SELECT * FROM #Personas  /*2*/

BEGIN TRAN                            
DELETE FROM #Personas   /*1*/           
SELECT * FROM #Personas                               
ROLLBACK                               
SELECT * FROM #Personas /*2*/
```

**Estos son los resultados:**

```
/*1*/
```

```
+-------------------------+
| IdPersona | Nombre      |
+-------------------------+
|           |             |
+-------------------------+

/*2*/
```

```
+-------------------------+
| IdPersona | Nombre      |
+-------------------------+
|    1      | Pablo       |
+-------------------------+
|    2      | Juan        |
+-------------------------+
|    3      | Carlos      |
+-------------------------+
```

**Ejemplo Identity**

```
   BEGIN TRAN 
   TRUNCATE TABLE #Personas
   INSERT INTO #Personas VALUES ('Marcos')
   SELECT * FROM #Personas /*1*/
   ROLLBACK 

   BEGIN TRAN
   DELETE
   FROM #Personas
   INSERT INTO #Personas VALUES ('Marcos')
   SELECT * FROM #Personas /*2*/
   ROLLBACK
```

**Estos son los resultados:**

```
/*1*/
```

```
+-------------------------+
| IdPersona | Nombre      |
+-------------------------+
|    1      | Marcos      |
+-------------------------+

/*2*/
```

```
+-------------------------+
| IdPersona | Nombre      |
+-------------------------+
|    4      | Marcos      |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Porque no simplemente pones la ruta de la respuesta http://stackoverflow.com/a/12900557/6901227

Comment: Porque no es la misma. Esa es general y yo hablo solo de SQL Server 2008 o superior. Por otro lado está en inglés. Y además tengo ejemplos de SQL Server 2008...

Comment: seria bueno que hagas referencia a la respuesta en ingles pero tu la traduciste, obviamente la tuya es mas completa ya que agregas ejemplos, +1

Comment: @sioesi gracias por la sugerencia, pero no sé si estaría bien poner el link. Por ejemplo en esa respuesta dice que "_no se puede hacer rollback de un Truncate_" cuando en SQL Server 2008 sí se puede. Por otro lado no explica que el Delete no resetea al Identity.

Answer (score 1):

**DELETE**

Borra una serie de filas de la tabla. Podemos usar una claúsula WHERE para limitar las filas a borrar, a las que cumplan una condición. La sintaxis sería:

```
DELETE FROM nombre_tabla WHERE condicion
```

Para nuestro caso:

```
DELETE FROM entradas WHERE id = 2;
```

**TRUNCATE**

A diferencia de DELETE, TRUNCATE elimina todas las filas de la tabla sin borrar la tabla. :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE nombre_tabla;
```

Y para nuestro caso:

TRUNCATE TABLE entradas;

Ahora que sabemos en que consiste cada sentencia, veamos las semejanzas y diferencias:

- Ambas eliminan los datos, no la estructura.
- Solo DELETE permite la eliminación condicional de los registros.
- DELETE es una operación registrada en el log de transacciones, basada en registrar cada eliminación individual.
- TRUNCATE es una operación registrada en el log de transacciones, pero como un todo, en conjunto, no por eliminación individual. TRUNCATE se registra como una liberación de las páginas de datos en las cuales existen los datos.
- TRUNCATE es más rápida que DELETE.
- Ambas se pueden deshacer con un ROLLBACK.
- TRUNCATE reiniciará el contador para una tabla que contenga una columna IDENTITY.
- DELETE mantendrá el contador de la tabla para una columna IDENTITY.
- TRUNCATE es un comando DDL(lenguaje de definición de datos) mientras que DELETE es un DML(lenguaje de manipulación de datos).
- TRUNCATE no desencadena un TRIGGER, DELETE sí.