# ELIMINAR REGISTROS DE LA BASE DE DATOS A TRAVÉS DE UN BOTÓN php

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

***Hola gente buenos días. Espero me puedan ayudar como siempre.***

**Mi pregunta es corta. Quería saber cómo puedo poner un botón en mi página PHP que me limpie todos los registros de mi tabla de base de datos.**

**

> lo siento si no me exprese correctamente, tengo una base de datos con
>   1000 tablas y quiero borrar todos los datos que contengan las tablas,
>   es decir limpiar o vaciar el contenido . pero no borrar la base de
>   datos o las tablas. solo la información

**

Comment: Ejecutas un delete a la tabla? esa es la pregunta?

Comment: a mi me da a entender que sí,pero creo que igual podría ser más específico

Comment: No se si el problema es hacer el boton, o ejecutar el delete a la base o cual es el problema. Podrias ser mucho mas especifico?

Comment: lo siento si no me exprese correctamente, tengo una base de datos con 1000 tablas y quiero borrar todos los datos que contengan las tablas, es decir limpiar o vaciar el contenido . pero no borrar la base de datos o las tablas. solo la información

Comment: Vas a apretar 1000 veces un boton? creo que tu pregunta deberia haber sido otra cosa, y aunque la solucion propuesta es correcta, yo no la usaria para borrar 1000 tablas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creas un botón y la mandas a una pagina donde ejecute el DELETE en la tabla deseada.

Se puede crear de otras  maneras esta es la más sencilla.

Creas el botón en **boton.php**

```
    <from action="eliminar.php" method="post">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
```

En tu página **eliminar.php**

```
    <?php
    // Si recibe el POST enviar ejecuta la eliminación
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Crear conexión
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Comprobar conexión
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("La conexión ha fallado: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    // Eliminamos todos los registros de la tabla mitabla
    $sql = "DELETE FROM mitabla";

    // Versión con TRUNCATE [*]
    // $sql = "TRUNCATE FROM mitabla"; 

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Eliminación completada";
    } else {
        echo "Se ha producido un error. Error: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
    ?>
```

[*] Como comentaba el compañero @MoteCL, es posible e incluso mejor en su opinión, usar TRUNCATE

Hilo sobre TRUNCATE Y DELETE : [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre TRUNCATE y DELETE?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38926/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-truncate-y-delete)

---

**Seguridad**

Como bien comenta @gbianchi (en los comentarios) este código es demasiado accesible y cualquiera podría acceder y eliminar la tabla sin más. La respuesta se centra en la funcionalidad sin más.

Más información sobre cómo proteger con un Token esta funcionalidad: http://www.notas-programacion.com/2014/10/generacion-de-tokens-de-seguridad-y-validacion-en-bd-mysql/

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! En general, tratamos de no contestar preguntas que no aclaren un problema especifico. Tene en cuenta que tambien esto podria llegar a ser un fallo de seguridad enorme, cualquiera que pudiera mandar un post borraria la tabla sin mayores problemas. Y otra cosa, el where 1=1 porque seria necesario?

Comment: mejor un `"TRUNCATE TABLE mitabla"`

Comment: La parte de where 1=1 realmente no es necesaria simplemente asegura que siempre se ejecute aunque es innecesaria. Y TRUNCATE o DELETE funciona más o menos igual. Modificó la respuesta para aportar estos cambios.

Comment: @gbianchi si es cierto, es un tanto tosco. Pero me centre en responder la funcionalidad.